# how change url array params by jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url, parameters

I need to change URL param By JavaScript or jquery.

My URL is:

```
domain.com/path/to/reach/5?order%5Bsort%5D=2&c=5
```

I want change paramt c and order[sort]

like this:

```
domain.com/?order%5Bsort%5D=3&c=15
domain.com/5?order%5Bsort%5D=2&c=16
domain.com/5?order%5Bsort%5D=1&c=17
```

my code is this:

```
regEx = /([?&]p)=([^#&]*)/g;
dataUrl = dataUrl.replace(regEx, '$1='+page);
regEx = /([?&]order[[]column[]])=([^#&]*)/g;
dataUrl = dataUrl.replace(regEx, '$1='+data["order[column]"]);
```

but don't work!!!!

Comment: Why do you have a `p` in the first group: `([?&]p)`? And why `column` in the second regex?

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use one of existing solutions like [**qs**](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) or [**URLSearchParams**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) for managing query-strings. It will make things **a lot** easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
let orderSort=4,c=6;
let url='domain.com/path/to/reach/5?order%5Bsort%5D=2&c=5';
let result=url.replace(/order%5Bsort%5D=\d*&c=\d*/,'order%5Bsort%5D='+orderSort+'&c='+c);
console.log(result);//domain.com/path/to/reach/5?order%5Bsort%5D=4&c=6
```

explanation:

i extract the key you offered and use the value to make a new and target string.

then, replace function works by replace the whole string the reg matches with the target string.

Comment: @Thefourthbird ，i simplified the code,,,i guess now is more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the order of the parameters, it's not possible to use your code. So I used the following code, but the first two lines worked correctly, but the second two lines have problems and add the value to it every time.

```
dataUrl = dataUrl.replace(/c=\d*/, 'c='+count);
dataUrl = dataUrl.replace(/p=\d*/, 'p='+page);
dataUrl = dataUrl.replace(/order%5Bsort%5D=\d*/, 'order%5Bsort%5D='+dataObj["order[sort]"]); //
dataUrl = dataUrl.replace(/order%5Bcolumn%5D=\d*/, 'order%5Bcolumn%5D='+dataObj["order[column]"]);
```